# How can I bulk load CSV files into Snowflake with the filename added as a column?

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can bulk load CSV files into Snowflake via an internal stage, or by directly loading the data into a table.

The problem I have is that the filename contains vital information and must be included in the table.

How I can bulk load CSV files into Snowflake, whilst adding the filename as an additional column?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the meta column `metadata$filename` for this, as in:

```sql
select metadata$filename
  , metadata$file_row_number
  , t.$1, t.$2 from @mystage1 (file_format => myformat) t;
```

See https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html